# SSAS security: is one role per user practical?

Tags: security, ssas, roles, olap-cube

We have to authorize hundreds of users for a cube, and the users must be restricted to individual dimension members. Two dimensions are relevant for the permissioning, a datatype permission (with only 10 members) and a customer dimension (with 2000+ members).

Since one user can be permissioned for any number of datatypes and customers, we could build one role per datatype and one role per customer... ending up with 2010+ roles. The datatype roles are not authorized for any customers and vice versa, therefore we could enable users for any combination of datatypes and customers.

On the other hand, if we create one role per user, we end up with only hundreds of roles. I therefore do not see the benefit of roles in our scenario. We will probably use AMO to maintain the roles.

My question is, if there is a penalty when using one role per user or it this is a tested method. Of course I am also interested in any alternative approach.

Comment: Have you considered [data-driven security](https://gavinrussell.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/analysis-services-%E2%80%93-data-driven-security-model/)?  Create a mapping table and just a couple of roles. Since security is additive, you may be able to make one role for data type and one role for customers and then feed it the mapping table.

Comment: Also, this may be relevant https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/why-not-to-use-the-external-assembly-approach-for-dynamic-security/

Comment: @mmarie I looked up the data driven security and tried it out. To no success yet, I have to give the authorized users group access to the role, but I get an exception when I try that. I still could give the users individual access - additional overhead. Also, the security measure group contains > 1 mio. rows and must be reloaded whenever the permissioning changes. I also had problem with the "allow" MDX clause, it would always present an error - maybe only at design time. However, the clause did not actually seem to reduce the number of available members..

Answer (score -1):

Problem in this case is that you don't have any data that would help you automate the roles.

So in order to make use of suggestions by mmarie you will need to further develop your cube and to maintain the user-customer relationship somehow (more horrible admin work).

Technically your scenario seems simple enough to be handled by http://easyroles.com which was made specifically to help out in these situations.

Disclaimer: I am involved with eR tool, but there is no other way I can answer this question since there are no other tools that are made for this.

Comment: We must use only the Microsoft BI tools tools stack in this project, no 3rd party components allowed. Would be interesting to know if the tool generates one role per possible set of permissions or one role per user.

Comment: eR is all based on MS products since it is a .NET application which uses SQL Server DB.

It creates one role per dimension member, not AD group/user. Though it does not entirely matter in this case since you never maintain the roles themselves; all the setup and maintenance work is done via eR interface.